# Axios network error when making request to local express server on Android device but works fine on emulator?

Tags: android, reactjs, express, expo

I'm trying to test my React Expo app on my android device and use an express backend on my laptop that I'm trying to point to.

Here's an overview of the setup:

- Android device running apk after `eas build`
- Macbook running express server with ip of `192.168.1.44`

In my React Expo app, I make the following request:

```
return await axios.get(`${constants.BASE_URL}/auth/code`, {});
```

Where `BASE_URL` is `BASE_URL: "http://192.168.1.44:8000"`

I have a seperate Macbook where I run my expo app on an android emulator and it can successfuly communicate with my expressjs Macbook and make the request.

However once I build and install the apk on my Android phone, I get an `AxiosError: Network Error`.

I printed out an alert and it returns the correct url on the app so I know the url is correct.

Things I've tried so far:

- Verified there is no firewall on ExpressJs Macbook
- Verified request url is correct on built APK by logging out url on phone
- Verified it works via emulator and laptop to laptop communication works

Any idea if this is some sort of network permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using ngrok to expose the server, not the most secure but it works in the meantime